# Reduce blue light on LCD monitor

Tags: display, lcd, eye-strain

My work LCD monitor has four settings for Color:

- warm (5000K)
- standard (6500K)
- cool (9300K)
- custom (each of the RGB values can be chosen separately)

What is the setting that could reduce at most blue light? I mean: changing color temperature would effectively affect the amount of blue light emitted, or it's just a graphic setting?

Or it's changed somewhere else on the monitor? Note that the monitor doesn't have a Blue Filter on/off option, otherwise I'd already have set it.

I'm not interested in software solutions - such as [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/) - because I am not allowed to install them.

Comment: Do you mean your image has a blue cast?

Comment: Well, what did you see when you tried the first 3, & what conclusions would you draw from that?

Comment: Go to custom and turn the blue all the way down. Voila.

Comment: @Tetsujin What I mean is, changing color temperature would effectively affect the amount of blue light emitted?  I've edited the question.

Comment: its a very 80s solution but there's apparently filters you can stick in front of tour monitors for that kinda thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the temperature to "warm" - or in other words, the lowest Kelvin) will give you the yellowest (reddest, actually, but it will look yellow) - and thus least blue setting.

6500 is equivalent to a "white looking" daylight LED bulb. 5000 is, from memory, equivalent to the yellow ones which look like the old incandescent bulbs.

Are you aware you can get glasses which remove the blue component of the light arround you? (gamers use them)

Comment: I've done this on my home monitor.  On my work monitor, I changed the RGB values lowering the B component from 255 to 200.  In both cases this reduced eye strain sensibly.  Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

> I mean: changing color temperature would effectively affect the amount of blue light emitted, or it's just a graphic setting?

## Both.

It does affect the amount of blue light emitted. It is just a graphic setting.

All colors are made by mixing light of three colors: red, green and blue, in appropriate amounts. Reducing amount of blue light = making the color less blue. It's literally the same thing. If it appears less blue, then less blue light is emitted.